# Negative optimization result in Answer Set Programming

Tags: optimization, logic-programming, answer-set-programming

I have written an ASP program with an optimization condition in the end. When I compile it, even though I get the correct result, in the summary I get a negative value for the optimization (i.e. `-3`).

[image]

Do you know why this happens?

The optimization code part looks like this:

```
number_of_leaves(N) :- #count{X : leaf(X)} = N.
#maximize {N : number_of_leaves(N)}.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In clingo only `#minimize` is actually implemented. `#maximize` is realized by using `#minimize` - just with negated values. Therefore the "maximum" is negated as well - it shows `-3` when the value should be `3`.